# Invalid username or password eroor page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm setting up a Car Sales project and I want an error page whenever I enter wrong username or password.

I have tried with the [HandleError] attribute, now I'm trying with Membership.ValidateUser. I'm a bit confused about which one I should use all I know is HandlerError attribute is for specific errors.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User user)
{
    using (CarsDBEntities db = new CarsDBEntities())
    {
        var usr = db.Users.Single(u => u.Email == user.Email && u.Password == user.Password);
        if (usr != null)
        {
            Session["UserId"] = usr.UserId.ToString();
            Session["Email"] = usr.Email.ToString();
            Session["FirstName"] = usr.FirstName.ToString();
            Session["LastName"] = usr.LastName.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
        }
        if (!Membership.ValidateUser(usr.Email, usr.Password))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password is incorrect");
            return View(user);
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is my view

```
@model Car_Sales.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>User</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I expected it to show an error which tells the user that he/she entered incorrect credentials.

Comment: Side note: it's a terrible idea to store passwords, you should be salting and hashing them.

Comment: Thank you, I will take that into consideration after I have done this task.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just [redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) to a new View or  Action or Controller?

Example:

```
if (!Membership.ValidateUser(usr.Email, usr.Password))
{
       return RedirectToAction("Error","SomeAction")
}
```

Comment: Multi-line code should be prefixed with 4 spaces.  Use backticks for inline code.

Comment: It doesn't work. It keeps showing the Yellow-Error page where you can see my code.